# (Javascript/AJAX) Pass multiple variables to onClick function

Tags: javascript, ajax, parameters, quotes

I'm trying to send multiple variables as parameters to a function (**redi**) called on an onClick event. At the moment I'm sending only one (**id**), can't find the way to send multiple (I want to send to it **id, nome, cognome**). I've tried with **onclick='redi(this.id, nome, cognome)'** but seems to be an error due to quotes (nome, cognome are strings).

```
$.ajax({

   url: "<URL to backend script>",
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
   timeout: 5000,
   success: function(data, status){
       $.each(data, function(i,item)
       { 
         var id = item.registrationID;
         var nome = item.registrationName;
         var cognome = item.registrationSurname;
         var id_referenza = item.registrationUsername;

         document.getElementById('divPaziente').innerHTML += "<a href='"+nome+"'><button class='button button-block button-positive' id='"+id+"' onclick='redi(this.id)'>"+nome+' '+cognome+' - '+id_referenza+"</button></a>";

         window.redi = function(elem)
         {
           alert("elem: "+elem);
           localStorage.setItem("id", elem);
         }
        });
        },
        error: function()
        {
          output.text('There was an error while loading data.');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'data-' attributes.

```
<a href='"+nome+"'><button class='button button-block button-positive' id='"+id+"' data-nome="'+nome+'" onclick='redi(this.id,this.getAttribute("data-nome"))'>"+nome+' '+cognome+' - '+id_referenza+"</button></a>
```

Note: Please avoid using innerHTML, instead use appendChild()

Answer (score 0):

Passing the other variables as a string using escape characters

```
redi(this.id,\'' + nome + '\',\'' + cognome + '\')
```

Comment: Now console returns "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

Comment: Try this- redi(' + this.id + ',' + nome + ',' + cognome + ').Meanwhile, the error is usually caused by a typo. check if there are matched quotes

Comment: Still not working, consider that nome could be something like "Lawrence".